# TypeScript and JS-like singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to implement Singleton pattern in TypeScript. I have found a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/k33g/3959903) but it seems like an overkill for me. After all, JavaScript is great in creating singletons.

Is it possible to write in TypeScript something like this (without getting an error)?

```
module Helpers {
    Helpers.Singleton = {};
}
```

Currently, it correctly generates the output that I am expecting:

```
// Module
var Helpers;
(function (Helpers) {
    Helpers.Singleton = {};
})(Helpers || (Helpers = {}));
```

But why is TypeScript compiler inside my VisualStudio complaining about that (it says that it "Could not find symbol 'Helpers'." at line 2!)? Is it possible to write it in another way?

[image: Left side shows generated code, right side illustrates the error highlight by VisualStudio]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
module Helpers {
    export module Singleton {
        export var etc = 4;
        export function printSomething() {
            // etc
        }
    }
}

// later...
Helpers.Singleton.printSomething();
```

Comment: Why isn't enough to export just the Singleton module? but all its properties and functions? thanks